# XSLT to move XML sibling to child

Tags: xml, xslt

Let me start by saying I have no idea what I'm doing with XSLT.  All of the XSLT I have I inherited from other people.  I have some XML (it's EAD if that helps) that is not formed the way our stylesheets expect it to be and therefore it will not properly transform into XHTML.

Basically, I need for the `<unitdate>` to be the child of the `<unittitle>`, not its sibling.

Most of the document looks like this:

```
<c03 id="ref13" level="file">
<did>
<unittitle>1. President (White House)</unittitle>
<container id="cid192710" type="Box" label="Text">1</container>
<container parent="cid192710" type="Folder">2</container>
<unitdate normal="1953/1956" type="inclusive">1953-1956</unitdate>
</did>
</c03>
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
<c03 id="ref13" level="file">
<did>
<unittitle>1. President (White House)<unitdate normal="1953/1956" type="inclusive">1953-1956</unitdate></unittitle>
<container id="cid192710" type="Box" label="Text">1</container>
<container parent="cid192710" type="Folder">2</container>
</did>
</c03>
```

Is there a simple way to do this?  I know there are similar questions, but I don't understand this well enough to adapt them to make it work properly.  Thanks.

Comment: wihtout the xslt processing this xml, we can't do much. It will probably be a relative easy task (if the xslt's are decent in the first place)

Comment: Rather than messing with the XSLT that changes this into XHTML, I was hoping to just change the XML itself so the XSLT I already have will work properly.  Is that not possible?

Comment: Surely is; use another XSLT to run before your existing XSLT's.

Comment: Exactly.  But I don't know how to write that interim XSLT to do what I need.

Comment: @Marvin means the following: We assume that your input XML is too large to reformat it by hand. Therefore, you'll need an XSLT stylesheet anyway to append unitdate to unittitle. Again: Can you share the stylesheet that transforms your data?

Answer (score 2):

Try these templates:

```
<xsl:template match="unittitle[following-sibling::unitdate]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="following-sibling::unitdate"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="unitdate"/>
```

And the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The identity template copies everything exactly as-is. The two previous templates override it in the specific cases where you have a `unittitle` element with a `unitdate` sibling following it, and the `unitdate` element itself.

You'll probably notice the first template is almost identical to the identity template- this is because it copies the `unittitle` the same way the identity one does, except it also copies the following `unitdate` element as well, after processing everything else (i.e. the text).

The one-line `unitdate` template simply removes it from where it was by handling it, and not outputting anything.

Answer (score 0):

To not modify the existing XSLT's and still be able to process the incxoming XML you can use the following XSLT (1.0) segment to solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="did">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()!='unitdate']"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="unittitle">
       <xsl:element name="unittitle">
             <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
             <xsl:copy-of select="../unitdate" />
       </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But your should seriously consider NOT using this. Modifying the existing XSLT's is the reasonable thing to do. This only produces performance overhead.

Comment: I definitely understand the reasoning as to why this is not the best approach, but since this was just a one-off fix, the "easy" way was much appreciated.  It worked fine and saved me a lot of angst.  Many thanks!